# How can I POST S3 bucket files to an external (non-AWS) cloud server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I transfer S3 files to an external server via POST request without having to download the files locally? The REST API only allows transfers within AWS.

Comment: Amazon S3 cannot "send" files. You would need to run code _somewhere_ that downloads from S3 and uploads to your destination.

Answer (score 0):

You need some computing for that. Easiest thing would be to do that with Lambda.

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what that would look like? Kind of new to this. What do you mean by computing? Also, for the Lamda function, you think I would be able to use the Python requests library to POST the files?

Comment: You write standard function, you can use any dependencies/labraries. You just need to invoke that in a lambda handler. I'd start by reading this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Answer (score 0):

There are **several ways** of doing this, which are use-case specific. Due to lack of details in the question (are the files small, do you want to POST them automatically when new files are added to S3, how many files at once) its difficult to provide precise answer. Nevertheless, all the possibilities would involve you **writing some code** to handle the transfer to a third party.

Some possibilities are:

- for **small files** (few mega I would say), you could write lambda function for that. For per-existing files you could create [S3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) which would trigger a lambda function when done. The lambda would take the list of files from inventory, and identify the files for upload to a third part and perform it. For new files only, you could setup [S3 notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) for new files. The notification would trigger a lambda function whenever a new files is upload to S3, and it would post it to a third party.
- for **large files** you would have to use containers or dedicated Ec2 instances. They could periodically scan your bucket for new files, download them and upload to a third party.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate a little more on the second bullet point, what the process looks like? So the files would be store on the EC2 instance? How would I POST the files from the instance? Would I invoke a Lambda function? (And yes, I would like to POST them automatically! I should have clarified)